# Image that loops as it slides horizontally across the screen to look like its scrolling infinitely

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I would like to have a view controller that loops an image in the background to give the appearance of infinite scrolling. For example, If I were to use the image below, the left and right  edges match up perfectly, and would be used to give an infinite scrolling appearance. Does anyone know how I might go about setting this up? I have done some research and am lost. Thank you all!

[image: Infinite Scrolling Image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd do it this way.  **EDIT** Rather than leave it as an exercise for the reader, updated to show how to pan in either direction...

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL keepGoing;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL panRight;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageViewA;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageViewB;

- (void)getReady {

    // init theImage
    UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"theImage.png"];

    // get two copies of the image
    self.imageViewA = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:theImage];
    self.imageViewB = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:theImage];

    // place one in view, the other, off to the right (for right to left motion)
    NSInteger direction = (self.panRight)? 1 : -1;
    self.imageViewA.frame = self.view.bounds;
    self.imageViewB.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.bounds, direction*self.imageViewA.bounds.size.width, 0.0);

    [self.view addSubview:self.imageViewA];
    [self.view addSubview:self.imageViewB];
    self.keepGoing = YES;
}

- (void)go {
    NSInteger direction = (self.panRight)? 1 : -1;
    CGFloat offsetX = -direction*self.imageViewA.bounds.size.width;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{
        self.imageViewA.frame = CGRectOffset(self.imageViewA.frame, offsetX, 0);
        self.imageViewB.frame = CGRectOffset(self.imageViewB.frame, offsetX, 0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (self.keepGoing) {
            // now B is where A began, so swap them and reposition B
            UIImageView *temp = self.imageViewA;
            self.imageViewA  = self.imageViewB;
            self.imageViewB = temp;
            self.imageViewB.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.bounds, direction*self.view.bounds.size.width, 0.0);
            // recursive call, but we don't want to wind up the stack
            [self performSelector:@selector(go) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
        }
    }];
}
```

To make it go, set the panRight property, then call `[self getReady];` and `[self go];`.

It will run mostly asynch.  To make it stop, `set self.keepGoing = NO;`.

Comment: Working with it now. Thanks! for the like "[self.view addSubView:self.imageViewA];" I am getting the error "@no visible interface for UIView declares the selector..." Any ideas on how to resolve?

Comment: oops... that's addSubview no cap on "V"

Comment: got it. One other thing. Line "UIViewAnimateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{" says error: use of undeclared identifier UIViewAnimateWithDuration... never used animate before

Comment: Yes.  sorry again.  typo... [UIView animateWithDuration... space and lowercase "a".  Also, please notice the use of self inside the animation block.  I was referring to the properties directly, which is poor form.

Comment: OK its looking good, any ideas on how I might be able to make it run smoothly? it slows down every time it loops - THANK YOU BY THE WAY!

Comment: Yes.  The default timing option is called ease-in-ease-out, and we want linear timing.  Will edit now.  See the [UIView animateWithDuration call now.

Comment: TOTALLY AWESOME - YOU ROCK! THANKS

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23070/discussion-between-brandon-and-danh)

Comment: Glad it works.  Sorry for the typos.  Just did it out of my head.  Should have run the code somewhere before posting.  (its on my sim right now with your image...looking cool!)

Comment: Hi Danh, I just noticed that the first time it loops the edge shows somehow I loaded it with this image as well and am experiencing the same glitch. http://preview.turbosquid.com/Preview/Content_2009_11_23__07_17_30/Brick_04_R.jpg7898ad5e-25b1-479d-a22c-ed9e3a006708Larger.jpg. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to make the image twice the width of the screen. Place it at 0,0. Animate it left and right as you desire. As soon as the origin is less than the negative of half the image width on the x axis it's reached the end of its right edge and as soon as the the origin is above 0 in the x axis it's reached the end of its left edge. When that happens, you can just reset the origin.